# XHR Interceptor in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, xmlhttprequest

Why is the following monkey patch not allowed in Typescript?

```js
const oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (
    method: string,
    url: string
): void {
    return oldXHROpen.apply(this, [method, url])
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
Argument of type '[string, string]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[method: string, url: string | URL, async: boolean, username?: string | null | undefined, password?: string | null | undefined]'.
  Source has 2 element(s) but target requires 3.
```

However when looking at the definitions of `open` there is a method which only requires two arguments.

```js
open(method: string, url: string | URL): void;
```

Comment: It's a design limitation in TypeScript, see [ms/TS#38353](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38353).  When manipulating function types with multiple call signatures, the compiler tends to drop all but one of them (usually the last one).  If you care about workarounds you can widen/assert that `oldXHROpen` has the one call signature you care about, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbAA9N).  Note there's still an error because that overload does not accept more than 2 arguments.

Comment: I can write that up as an answer if it meets your needs, but I wonder if you don't mind [edit]ing the example to get rid of `args` (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAjjZW)) because it is not directly relevant to the question as asked and just causes a distracting different error.  If it doesn't meet your needs let me know what's missing.

Comment: Okay thank you for the explanation. I edited my post to get rid of the additional `args`-error. Please provide your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#38353](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38353) for more information.

The [TypeScript standard library's typings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38353) for [the `XHMLHttpRequest.open()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) looks like this:

```
interface XMLHttpRequest {
    open(method: string, url: string | URL): void;
    open(method: string, url: string | URL, async: 
      boolean, username?: string | null, password?: string | null): void;
}
```

There are two call signatures, which makes `open()` an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) method in TypeScript.  If you call an overloaded method or function directly, the compiler will select one of the overloads based on the parameters you pass in.

But it is unable to do this purely at the type level.  If you start to programmatically manipulate the type of an overloaded function type, the compiler will just immediately pick one call signature without trying to figure out which one is the most appropriate for the situation.  Usually this is the last call signature.

In this case, presuming you have [the `--strictBindCallApply` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#strictbindcallapply) enabled, [the `apply()` method for `CallableFunction`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b7b648306f46c14dd6220f9ea1c6528970db4f81/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L335) only sees the second call signature for `XHMLHttpRequest.open()`.  That call signature requires at least three parameters, so the compiler gets angry when you `apply()` two of them.  Oops.

---

The workaround in this situation is for you to manually widen the type of `oldXHROpen` from a pair of call signatures to the single call signature you're trying to support.  Since widening is a safe operation, you can do this with a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) and not give up any type safety:

```
const oldXHROpen: (method: string, url: string | URL) => void =
  window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open // okay
```

Once you do that, the `apply()` method only sees the `open()` call signature you care about, and everything works:

```
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (
  method: string,
  url: string
): void {
  return oldXHROpen.apply(this, [method, url])  // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9AVAlgdgLgUwE4DMCGBjBACAGgWQBkAJOOABwCUEBHAVwQGc5sBvUbbAe3IRgAoAtgjgALLgBMAXNmZJYAcwA02OkgA2MuYuwAfbAFVKhAJQyAblygSA3B268BwsZK1x5MZao1uPCvYbGKmiMAJ4wGDIARlxc6ghoMCp0jMgwaMIA-L46+jB06uoq5CGMAO5cSBLZsu652PmFZtiW1nYgAL4QYKCgGFwwzNzqErjElADyjjJCIuLStX7JPov1RqbYALwAfC1WElv2ZbASXGUAdAQkZFS0DMzn5EhccC+hvOc8fL0gxzCnFyupAo1HoTDgj2erzg7wQn0cW2wKDoETgUAG2H49mc8xyniU9jUmlWnlAzVaB3YIE4SBEahgw1G4ymfHOaHI5HUoX4YigjBUAG0cZJluoALomThgMDcADWaFCoA6QA)